# How to configure PhpStorm short tags indentation

Tags: coding-style, phpstorm

Here is the indentation that PhpStorm will generate for this code:

```
<?php if (count($foo) > 0) : ?>
<div>...</div>
<?php else : ?>
<p>...</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I configure it to be simply:

```
<?php if (count($foo) > 0) : ?>
    <div>...</div>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>...</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible right now to indent code this way, please [submit a request to YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WI).

Comment: Thanks. For people having the same problem as I do, follow the issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11118